# Return a value from the child JPanel to the parent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel

I have a `MainFrame` class where I hold a `JFrame` and open a new `JPanel` as `LoginPanel`. In this `LoginPanel` class I have a login button and an `ActionListener`. The action listener should check the login credentials and then return to the `MainFrame` class any value maybe a `boolean` so I can open a new `JPanel` for the corresponding user:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
...
this.loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
this.add(loginPanel);

--> Here I would like to open a new JPanel and open a new JPanel 
    for the logged in user based on the value returned by the LoginPanel

...
}
```

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel{
...
// Create the action for the login button
   loginButton.addActionListener(e -> {
       // TODO: check if the given username is available
       // TODO: return maybe a boolean so we know that the user logged in succesfully
   });
```

I would be very thankful for any Idea on how to change my software design to implement this logic.
Cheers!

Comment: Note: answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Your question involves multiple steps, I'm afraid, but the bottom line is how to get one object to communicate with another, and the standard way to do this is by calling public methods of one into the other. One simple way is to give your  LoginPanel class a MainFrame field, one that is filled via a constructor:

```
public class LoginPanel {
    private MainFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton loginButton = ....;
    
    public LoginPanel(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        
        loginButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            // extract the key properties from this class
            // such as text in a JTextField and the char[] in a password field
            // test it for appropriateness, and then send the information 
            // to the mainFrame object by calling a method
            
            // e.g.,
            // mainFrame.userVerified(/* boolean test in here */);
            
            // e.g.,
            mainFrame.userVerified(
                    userNameField.getText().equals(someUserNameVariable)
                    && Arrays.equals(passwordField.getPassword(), someCharArrayVariable));
        });
    }
```

So MainFrame would need to pass itself into LoginPanel:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        // ...
        loginPanel = new LoginPanel(this);
        add(loginPanel);
        // ...
    }
    
    public void userVerified(boolean verified) {
        // act on it, swapping JPanels using a CardLayout
    }
```

A *better* solution, one that "scales well" is to separate concerns, the GUI from the non-GUI model and use a Model-View-Controller or similar type structure, but for your purposes, that may be over-kill at this point.

---

Another potential solution is to extract out the logic from the LoginPanel and into the Main program (or better yet, the program's "model"), and instead give the LoginPanel methods that allow us to extract the data that the user enters as well as a method to allow an outside class to add an ActionListener to the LoginPanel's login button, something that simplified looks like this:

```
class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    // ...
    private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(FIELD_COLS);
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(FIELD_COLS);
    private JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

    public LoginPanel() {       
        // ...
    }
    
    public void addLoginListener(ActionListener listener) {
        loginButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameField.getText();
    }
    
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }
    
    // ....
    
}
```

Then the LoginPanel needs to have absolutely no knowledge about how it is being used or who is using it, reducing coupling somewhat (a good thing). A listener can be passed into it, and can be structured like so:

```
loginPanel.addLoginListener(e -> {
    String userName = loginPanel.getUserName();
    char[] password = loginPanel.getPassword();
    
    // ...
    
});
```

A working example could look something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 8;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 24;
    private static final String LOGIN_PANEL = "login panel";
    private static final String TEXT_AREA = "text area";
    private LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public MainPanel() {
        cardLayoutPanel.add(loginPanel, LOGIN_PANEL);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(scrollPane, TEXT_AREA);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardLayoutPanel);
        
        loginPanel.addLoginListener(e -> {
            String userName = loginPanel.getUserName();
            String password = new String(loginPanel.getPassword()); // ***NEVER do this
            
            // here need more code to test if name and password are OK
            
            // then if OK, swap views:          
            textArea.append("User Name: " + userName + "\n");
            textArea.append("Password:  " + password + "\n");
            cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel, TEXT_AREA);
        });
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
            
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);         
        });
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private static final int FIELD_COLS = 12;
    private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(FIELD_COLS);
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(FIELD_COLS);
    private JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

    public LoginPanel() {       
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        add(new JLabel("UserName:"), createGBC(0, 0));
        add(userNameField, createGBC(1, 0));
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), createGBC(0, 1));
        add(passwordField, createGBC(1, 1));
        
        loginButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = createGBC(0, 2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        add(loginButton, gbc);
    }
    
    public void addLoginListener(ActionListener listener) {
        loginButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameField.getText();
    }
    
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }
    
    // create constraints that help position components in the GridBagLayout-using container
    private GridBagConstraints createGBC(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;     
    }
    
}
```

Note that for safety's sake, it is best not to create Strings out of password char arrays.